# How to restart a KafkaStreams topology in a way that avoids recreating the state store

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I wrote some codes with KafkaStreams DSL and processor api to realtime compute:

```
  KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
  KStream<String, String> logs = builder.stream(stringSerde, stringSerde, ADDCASH_TOPIC_NAME);

  StateStoreSupplier countStore = Stores.create("Counts")
            .withKeys(Serdes.String())
            .withValues(Serdes.Long())
            .persistent()
            .build();

 logs.process(() -> new AddCashProcessor(), countStore.name());
```

I want to know: When i restart the topology, if `Stores.create(..)`  method will recreate the StateStore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will reuse an existing state and only create and empty/new store if there is none.